# Warning (from warnings module): ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket object, fd=404, family=2, type=1, proto=0> using selenium

Tags: python, sockets, selenium

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("selenium")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        self.assertIn("Google", driver.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I am getting this warning. What is wrong?

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.37.2-py3.3.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 95
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket object, fd=400, family=2, type=1, proto=0>
```

Answer (score 23):

It's a known bug:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5923

It's safe to ignore it though. If you're using Python 3, you can do:

```
unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

See [Python 3 unittest docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main).

In Python 2, you'd use something like this:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True):
     unittest.main()
```

cf the [Python 2 warnings docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings)

If you'll forgive the shameless self-promotion, there's lots more info on selenium in a wee book I've written, [here](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com).

Comment: Where would we put the ignore warnings statement in our code? Would it be part of `def setUp()`?

Comment: does this suppress all warnings? is it possible to suppress just the `ResourceWarning`? Despite the age of this post and the link to Google code, this issue is still happening.

Answer (score 10):

I run my tests with the `-W` flag thus:

```
python -W ignore -m unittest my_tests
```

or

```
python -W ignore -m unittest my_tests.MyIndividualTest
```

that suppresses the `ResourceWarning` but still allows assertion error reports.

---

BTW I found that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

works when invoking `python my_tests.py` when every test is to be run, but this invocation precludes running individual tests.

I couldn't figure out how else to use `unittest.main(warnings='ignore')` without encountering errors I put down to recursive inclusion of `unittest` libraries.

(`selenium==2.44.0` under `Python 3.4.2`)